# Dynamically created gridview in asp.net doesn't have any values after saving into list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, webforms

I am creating an asp.net webform and ran into this problem: After I created a dynamically created gridview and I want to save it to a list of objects there doesn't seem to be any values in it. I added a breakpoint at the point where it loops through the rows in the gridview and it just jumps over the entire foreach loop.

Where I add the rows to the gridview:

```
DataTblKPI = (DataTable)ViewState["KPIs"];
            DataTblKPI.Rows.Add(drpKPIs.SelectedValue, txtKPIInput.Text);
            grdKPI.DataSource = DataTblKPI;
            grdKPI.DataBind();
```

Where I try to save it to a list of objects:

```
List<KPITest> dataList = new List<KPITest>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdKPI.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    string name = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    string desc = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                    dataList.Add(new KPITest { Name = name, Description = desc });
                }
            }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried several methods of saving it to the list. After this step I want to save it to a table in sql server.

Comment: 'jumps over the entire foreach loop' implies there are no rows in grdKPI.  Have you confirmed you have the data in the rows at this point?

Comment: The above should work. I think we need a bit more markup and information here, since what you have should in theory work just fine. Perhaps you using some kind of update panel, or maybe your trying to call + use some web method here? Is this code running on a button click, or what actions are  done to trigger such code? So, I think a few more details and more markup is required to help you with this question.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I had to bind the datatable again to the datagrid in the save button press. Thanks Albert and Timothy for your replies. I'll add some more markup next time when posting a question.